# rake figaro:heroku is returning an error with sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to set up my app on Heroku and as I understand it the issue I am having is resulting from trying to run `rake figaro:heroku`

Every time I run it I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/database
C:/Users/Zac/GitHub/Bitsy/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Users/Zac/GitHub/Bitsy/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

My gem file is set up as such:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '4.0.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem "paperclip-dropbox", ">= 1.1.7"
gem "figaro"
gem 'devise'

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end


group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

And my database.yml is as:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I have changed the production adapter and database previously and it doesn't seem to make a difference. I have spent about 5 hours searching for help on this to no avail so if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use sqlite3 on Heroku.. you have to use Postgres (you may already know that).

You should try to use the same db in development as production to avoid inconsistencies, so in this case, use PG in every environment.

.. but to fix your problem, try changing the database.yml production entry to:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: your_app_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

that should work